# How to convert a string which contains a hexadecimal number to an int in c

Tags: c, data-conversion

I have a situation where I have a char *, called number, which will either contain a decimal number in the form of ("123") or a hexadecimal number in the form ("0x123"), where 123 is arbitrary;

What is the best way to convert this string to an integer considering I don't know which format the char * will be in?

Comment: You must search the string for `0x`. If found, convert to `int` using `strtol`, for example, with base of `16` or `10`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Just use `strtol()` with a base of `0`.  If the data is decimal but can still start with 0, use a base `10` so the string is treated as decimal instead of octal.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Even better.